# Azure IoT Edge deployment file updated but removed docker container keeps running

Tags: azure, docker, containers, azure-iot-edge

I am changing the deployment file for Azure IoT Edge, removed redis docker create & its running state from deployment file. The deployment is correctly received by iot edge and changes are taking place but redis docker keeps running.
[image]

Even after forecefully stopping, deleting the container and removing the corresponding image, it keeps coming back and running. I see that on cloud side, it is not mentioned in deployment but status is running.
[image]
Is there any local cache which is bringing this ? How to fix this issue?

Comment: Hi Prasan, navigate to Set Modules tab under the IoT Edge module and check if you can still see the redis module under the IoT Edge Modules section. If you do, delete the module using delete icon from here and delete any existing routes related to the module. Perform an IoT edge runtime restart using `sudo iotedge system restart` and see if that helps.

Note that the run time restart will restart all the edge modules as well. The will be a momentary down time. So, plan accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I have intermittently encountered this issue. I am not sure of the root cause for this behavior. But here is what has helped me address this issue in the past.

- Navigate to Set modules tab on the IoT Edge device.
  [image]
- Look under the IoT Edge modules section and you should see the redis module.
- Click the delete button next to it.
  [image]
- Go to routes and delete any existing routes that are related to the redis module
- Click on review and create.

After making the above changes execute the following command on your IoT Edge device `sudo iotedge system restart`

Please note that the commands will restart the IoT Edge Run time and will bring down the modules momentarily.